# Check if executable is valid

Tags: unix, operating-system, ocaml

Suppose I want to check if some executable, `foo`, is valid prior to calling it with its arguments. Various means of doing so are available from the command line (e.g., `$> hash foo`).

However, to my knowledge, neither OCaml's `Sys` nor `Unix` modules provide such functionality build-in.

**How might one define idiomatically a mechanism that accepts a string indicating a unix executable and returns a bool indicating if the argument is executable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `file` command for this purpose.  `file` returns this for an executable:

```
file /bin/ls

output => ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x37cdd635587f519989044055623abff939002027, stripped
```

You can either parse the output or use one of many command line options that `file` command has.

Answer (score 5):

The function that allows you to check whether a file is executable or not is `Unix.access`. If you want to additionally search the path, you'll need additional scaffolding, e.g.:

```
let syspath = String.split_on_char ':' (Sys.getenv "PATH")

let check_executable path =
  let open Unix in
  try
    access path [ X_OK ]; Some path
  with _ -> None

let starts_with s prefix =
  let open String in
  let plen = length prefix in
  length s >= plen && sub s 0 plen = prefix

let search_path name =
  if starts_with name "/" || starts_with name "./" || starts_with name "../"
  then
    check_executable name
  else
    List.fold_left (fun acc dir ->
      match acc with
      | Some file -> Some file
      | None ->
        check_executable (Filename.concat dir name)
    ) None syspath

let main () =
  Array.iter (fun arg ->
    match search_path arg with
    | None -> Printf.printf "%s (Not found)\n" arg
    | Some file -> Printf.printf "%s -> %s\n" arg file)
  Array.(sub Sys.argv 1 (length Sys.argv - 1))

let () = main ()
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to codeforester's answer of using `file`, there are also bindings to libmagic which effectively gives you access to `file`'s output without the need to shell out.  See https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-magic, available in opam as `magic`.

Comment: What do you mean by "shell out"?

Comment: Calling out to an external program via shell (ex bash, cmd.exe, etc)

Answer (score 2):

To check if a file is executable, I would use the permission of the file - you can get them the following way :

> ```
>  let getstat f = (Unix.stat (Filename.basename f)).Unix.st_perm;;
>  Printf.printf "%d\n" (getstat ".bashrc");;
>  > 644
> ```

Showing that the x flags are set.